# Problems connecting iOS simulator from Xcode to Flutter via Visual Studio Code on my Macbook M1

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjXJy.png)So I'm trying to connect the simulator for iOS from Xcode to Flutter in Visual Studio Code on my MacOS. I'll send a few screenshots, however I already have the command line set up on Xcode, but I can't seem to run my Flutter app on VS Code. The play button isn't visible on VSC, I've tried to Googled several solutions, but I can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for. Every time I click on the run button, it just creates more errors and bugs on the output. I know this can't be that complicated. Anyone that can help me with this issue so that I can get started on Flutter, would really appreciate it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKNhW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhukI.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. click where at the bottom where it says "macOS"
2. a list will appear in the top "select a device to run", then select "start iOS simulator"
3. press F5 to run

Comment: In case it still doesn't show up, open the xcode > new project > click on the play/run > download xcode support for ios 17.

Comment: So I clicked on the MacOS tab and opened the command but it only shows emulator options, no "start iOS simulator". I updated my post by uploading a new  image  if you want to see it

Comment: Also I tried the first method and clicked on device MacOS. So I'll try the 2nd method

Comment: So this worked, but the only thing is that a play button doesn't appear on the upper right corner in VS Code. The play button appears on the tutorial Flutter video that I'm watching and he's using a MacOS. However the video is over a year old, so maybe I'm just overthinking and it's fine.

Comment: I actually got it fixed now. Thank you so much.